# Shutdown event for console application C#

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, event-handling, console-application

How can i know when my C# console application will be stopping? Is there any event or like that?

Thanks!

Comment: You want code to exit from app?

Comment: [this question is is similar with yours][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event of the application domain

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);           


        }

        static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that your code in CurrentDomain_ProcessExit will only be given a few seconds to execute before the application terminates anyway.

Comment: This will not help when user logs off or system reboots. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6799964/1051244). Since Console applications dont raise the SessionEnding event, add a hidden window to catch them. The hidden window can be inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Form and should be started in a seperate thread with Application.Run(myHiddenForm). In the load event of the form add your event handler to SystemEvents.SessionEnding which should gracefully stop your application.

Answer (score 6):

Handling the event `System.Console.CancelKeyPress` might help you.

[MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx) it how to handle this event along with other things that you need to take care of while handling this event, excerpt:

> This event is used in conjunction with
>   System.ConsoleCancelEventHandler and System.ConsoleCancelEventArgs.
>   The CancelKeyPress event enables a console application to intercept
>   the CTRL+C signal so the application can decide whether to continue
>   executing or terminate.
>
> Use this event to explicitly control how your application responds to
>   the CTRL+C signal. If your application has simple requirements, you
>   can use the TreatControlCAsInput property instead of this event.
>
> The event handler for this event is executed on a thread pool thread.