# Event when the console is Closing vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like my console launch a function when it closing, like that :

```
Sub Console_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
```

But, I'm not using Windows Form but the module, and I can't import Windows Form in the project.
Haven't you got an idea ?
Tanks ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119841/1271037 https://stackoverflow.com/q/4646827/1271037 https://stackoverflow.com/q/11291352/1271037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProcessExit` event of the `AppDomain`.

```
Sub Main
   AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit, AddressOf OnClose
End Sub

Sub OnClose(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
   'codeon close
End Sub
```

Comment: Tank you ! But, when I click on the close button, sub doesn't run. I will use links, tanks :)