# Tray application allow system to kill my program when logouting or exiting

Tags: c#, windows, workflow-foundation, exit, tray

My program is starting with windows, I have such code to prevent exiting application when user hits exit button:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

It is working very well, but when I want to turn off computer, every time I get screen like 'One or more application cannot be exited. Cancel - Exit despite this.

How can I allow windows to normally exit my application, but also prevent user from exiting it when click red exit button?

Comment: You better post an answer your self instead of adding an answer to your question.... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff).

In the [`SessionEnded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx) event handler, set a boolean like `sessionEnded` and in your OnClosing test for that value:

```
if (!sessionEnded)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped (thanks to CodeCaster):

```
    private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
    private static bool systemShutdown = false;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            systemShutdown = true;
        }

        // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
        // raised in the base WndProc.
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    } //WndProc 

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        if (!systemShutdown)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```