# Foreach Loop Cannot Convert Char To String

Tags: c#, windows, foreach

This seemingly simple for whatever reason is not working.  Specifically the Foreach Loop is giving me this error "Error 1   Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'". I have done some research although it does not want to reveal its self.  Hopefully you guys will know, thanks so much for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A_HtmlEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }               

        // The error occurs in the foreach loop below    
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = textBox1.Text;

            foreach(string s in textBox1.Text)
            {
                data.Add(s);
            } 
        }    
    }
}
```

As an aside
I was wondering while I am here, do any of you happen to know whether or not it is possible to find out if there was a button click, such as the shutdown button?  Or if that is not possible is there a way to know when a computer is about to be shutdown.

Once again I appreciate it all, Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`textBox1.Text` is a string (not a collection of strings). So when you do this:

```
foreach (string s in textBox1.Text)
{
    data.Add(s);
}
```

it is trying to treat the string as a collection. This actually works, because a `string` is really an array of `char`. The problem is that you're trying to convert each `char` to a `string` when you declare `string s`.

If you really want to add each character to `data`, then you can convert each `char` to a `string`:

```
// This takes each character from textBox1.Text,
// converts it to a string, and adds it to data
foreach (char chr in textBox1.Text)
{
    data.Add(chr.ToString());
}
```

Or, if your `textBox1` is a multi-line textbox and you're trying to add each line to `data`, you can split the text on the `NewLine` character to get a list of strings, and add them like so:

```
// This takes each line from a multi-line text box and adds it to data
foreach (string line in textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { '\n' }))
{
    data.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What it looks like you are trying to do is iterate through the lines of a textbox. The Text property of a TextBox object is of a data type String.

If I am correct, in order to accomplish this, you could do something like the following:

```
var lines = textbox.Text.Split((new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var s in lines)
{
   data.Add(s);
}
```

Because the Text property is a single string object. You would need to split the string into a collection of smaller strings on some sort of delimiter such as a new line character. (eg. '\n')

Answer (score 1):

A string contains characters not strings, change to the following

```
foreach(char s in textBox1.Text) //should be renamed to c as char
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to iterate characters in string you can use something

```
        foreach (var s in textBox1.Text)
        {
            data.Add(s.ToString());
        }
```

if you want to get the array of characters from string you can use

```
textBox1.Text.ToCharArray()
```

You can find the answers here for detecting power off 
[How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this would be:

```
string[] textBox1.text = webBrowser1.DocumentText
foreach (string s in textBox1.Text)
{
    data.Add(s);
}
```

By doing this they will be seen as separate str instead of char

Answer (score -1):

Or use this one if getting substring at particular position is concerned

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s[i]); // or other works 
    }
```