# C# How to detect kill event sender

Tags: c#, detect, shutdown

I have a `FormClosing` method for my program to ask the user if he want to exit the program before closing the form. This works great, but I don't want the dialog to show up when the program closes because of a system shutdown / logout. How can I detect that the kill command is sent by the system and not by the user clicking the x of my form? `Envrionment.HasShutdownStarted` does not work.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Need to check for system shutdown here before the next if is activated
    if (MessageBox.Show(...) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking `e.CloseReason`, e.g.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(...) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Activate();
        }
    }   
}
```