# How can my BackgroundService get notified when Windows shuts down?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a `BackgroundService` that needs to perform an operation before the OS shuts down. Is there any way to do this with an `IHostedService` since there isn't an `OnShutdown()` event like in `ServiceBase`?

I tried making it work by implementing `StopAsync`, but it started to add a lot of complexity to the project since that runs any time the service is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [`StopAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) and check for windows shutdown using Win32 API ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354976/2791540)).

```
const int SM_SHUTTINGDOWN = 0x2000
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task StopAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    bool isShuttingDown = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) != 0;
    if (isShuttingDown)
    {
        //Do your thing here
    }
}
```